# Difference between 12 byte and 6 byte color?

Tags: memory, colors

I have been around computers for a long time, however I have never seen color expressed in this format (until today):

```
0xebebdbdbb2b2
```

is there any difference between that interpretation and say:

```
#ebbdb2
```

Or is it that

```
#ebbdb2 = 0xebebdbdbb2b2
```

Are there any differences between the two? Does one represent the other?

I found the 12 byte colors in [this](https://gitlab.com/tsoding/aoc-2021/-/blob/0982db4c2d2736deefdb42b157b06f715a852130/Home/Theme.HC) repo. This is from a someones [TempleOS](https://github.com/cia-foundation/TempleOS) build. It is hard to tell what exactly the original creator of the OS meant for the values to be interpreted to.

Comment: This looks like colors that the program specifically uses .. NOT hex .. They start out as an actual number -- `0x`  denotes that it's a hexidecimal number.  For instance `0Xe` is 14 when converted to a hex decimal.  How it is parsed, and used will be native to that specific application.

Comment: @Zak Yeah, but surely doubling the bit count would produce higher numbers of colors, or color depth? I do get what you're saying though.

Comment: Note: you are speaking about 6 and 12 characters (not bytes). 0x1234567890ab will take 6 bytes. Just there are many different colour notation. 16-bit per channel is common, but it could be linear or "gamma corrected". But also endianess and channel order may be different (and not to forget we can have 16-bit half precision float instead of integers). Working space may have also different colour space. So we need much more details.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I added a little bit more info on where this is being used. Not sure if that helps. Still curious though!

Comment: Probably it is the same colour. HTML used #abc as short version (4-bit per channel colours) of #aabbcc (8-bit  channel colours). So I expect that someone will do the same with #a1b2c3 equivalente to #a1a1b1b1c1c1 (16-bit channel). So white remain white, and black remain black. OTOH on such large numbers, we may tend not to pack bits. Probably it is just a generalization (we have since many year screens which can show 10-bit per channel colours (so #aabbcc is not enough)